# How to sort a collection with price as string in the format "Rs. 350,40"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Javascript array with object containing price as string in the format as follows:

```
results:[{
image: "http://dummyhost/new3305-82-thumb.jpg",
product_title: "Nokia Lumia 1540",
price: "Rs. 50,790"
},
{
image: "http://dummyhost/new3305-82-thumb.jpg",
product_title: "Nokia Lumia 1520",
price: "Rs. 37,790"
}]
```

I know we can make use of the following function prototype to sort the value with string or   interger:

```
Array.prototype.sortByProp = function(p){
 return this.sort(function(a,b){
  return (a[p] > b[p]) ? 1 : (a[p] < b[p]) ? -1 : 0;
 });
}
```

I want the sort to happen for combination of string and integer where we get api response with   price specific to country currency format.

Comment: Can the result set be changed to have the currency in a separate property?

Comment: Add another field to each JSON which contains the integer converted version of the price and sort on that, maybe.

Comment: This is a response from a api, and i want to consume as it is so it   would be better if we can sort on existing collection without   introducing new field

Comment: Is the comma in the price a thousands separator or a decimal point?

Comment: comma is a separator.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a price in the format `"Rs. 50,790"` into a number as follows:

```
p = "Rs. 50,790";
p = +p.replace(/\D/g,"");
```

That is, do a regular expression replacement to remove all the non-digits from the string (assuming the comma is a thousands separator as mentioned in your comment), then use the unary plus operator to turn the resulting string into a number.

Then you can sort using the numeric values. I'm not sure how you'd want to incorporate that into your generic `sortByProp()` function though. Perhaps by adding a flag to tell it the property is to be converted into a number:

```
Array.prototype.sortByProp = function(p,isNumeric){
  return this.sort(function(a,b){
    a = isNumeric ? +a[p].replace(/\D/g,"") : a[p];
    b = isNumeric ? +b[p].replace(/\D/g,"") : b[p];

    return (a > b) ? 1 : (a < b) ? -1 : 0;
  });
};

results.sortByProp("price", true);
// or for other fields omit the second parameter or pass in false:
results.sortByProp("product_title");
```

Comment: string comparison check for the first char, not the entire value so this should not work for "57790" and "795", so it "works" for the data shown, but won't work in general.

Comment: @Hacketo - It's not doing a string comparison. As I already mentioned explicitly in my answer, the strings are being converted to numbers using the unary plus operator. `+"57790"` returns the *number* `57790`. Try typing `+"57790" > +"795"` into your browser console and see what happens...

Comment: Know that, but was reading += on the first statement. think this notation is crazy.

Comment: @Hacketo - Well, `p = Number(p.replace(/\D/g,""));` does the same thing in a more obvious way. Or use `parseFloat()`. But they're more to type...

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the price in a sort method

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b){
    var pA = parseFloat(a["price"].substr(4).replace(",", ""));
    var pB = parseFloat(b["price"].substr(4).replace(",", ""));

    if (pA < pB) return -1;
    if (pA > pB) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Edit : good point for the point

Comment: What happens to the comma? `parseFloat("37,790")` is 37. So it "works" for the data shown, but won't work in general.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Array.prototype.sortByProp = function(p){
    return this.sort(function(a,b){
        console.log(a,b)
        return (parseInt(a['price'].substring(4).replace(',','')) >   parseInt(b['price'].substring(4).replace(',',''))) ? 1 : 0;
     });
}
```

It takes a substring which starting with position 2 and then replaces `,` with nothing.
`parseInt(a['price'].substring(4).replace(',',''))`